# Groovy: Constructor hash collision

Tags: groovy, hash, constructor, collision

I have the following groovy code:

```
def    script
String credentials_id
String repository_path
String relative_directory
String repository_url

CredentialsWrapper(script, credentials_id, repository_name, repository_group, relative_directory=null) {
    this(script, credentials_id, 'git@gitlab.foo.com:' + repository_group +'/' + repository_name + '.git', relative_directory);             
}

CredentialsWrapper(script, credentials_id, repository_url, relative_directory=null) {

    this.script         = script;
    this.credentials_id = credentials_id;
    this.repository_url = repository_url;

    if (null == relative_directory) {

        int lastSeparatorIndex  = repository_url.lastIndexOf("/");
        int indexOfExt          = repository_url.indexOf(".git"); 
        this.relative_directory = repository_url.substring(lastSeparatorIndex+1, indexOfExt);
    }
}
```

Jenkins gives me the following:

Unable to compile class com.foo.CredentialsWrapper due to hash collision in constructors @ line 30, column 7.

I do not understand why, the constructors are different, they do not have the same number of arguments.

Also, "script" is an instance from "WorkflowScript", but I do not know what I should import to access this class, which would allow me to declare script explicitly instead of using "def"

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the Constructor with four parameters, would you like to call the first or the second one?

If you write an constructor/method with default values, groovy will actually generate two or more versions.
So

```
Test(String x, String y ="test")
```

will result in

```
Test(String x, String y) {...}
```

and

```
Test(String x) {new Test(x, "test")}
```

So your code would like to compile to 4 constructors, but it contains the constructor with the signature
`CredentialsWrapper(def, def, def, def)`
two times.
If I understand your code correctly, you can omit one or both of the `=null`. The result will be the same, but you will get only two or three signatures. Then you can choose between both versions by calling calling them with the right parameter count.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I finally made two constructor that needs no default values, and it is working.

Subsidiary question if you have an answer for this: when I call a method from the constructor, groovy fails with no error and the returned object is null (the script fails when trying to use the object). Would you know why ?

Comment: Glad I could help. Unfortunately I don't use Jenkins anymore and have no experience with Groovy inside Jenkins. I would try to narrow it down by adding log messages or printlines.

Comment: This is what I did, the constructor executes until it find a method, then it just stops. I know the methods are working fine and they do not need a completely built item or be within a node to work.

I will probably try to make a simple example and post another thread. Thank you

Comment: The issue you’re describing might be related to the fact that you’re using string manipulation methods which may cause trouble in Pipeline and sometimes need to be placed in a NonCPS method. On the other hand afaik constructors are usually always NonCPS. You may open a separate question for the constructor call issue, though.